# BASH: Array element becoming the name of a new array

Tags: arrays, bash

I've got an array `bucket1=('10' '22' 'bucket1')`

As you can see, one of the elements is the name of the array `bucket1`

Now I'm creating a new array by copying `bucket1`:

```
array1=("${bucket1[@]}")
```

Now I'm changing one of the elements in `array1`:

```
array1[1]='30'
```

`echo ${array1[@]}` gives `10 30 bucket1`

Now I want to feed that change back to the array `bucket1`, but without knowing that `array1` was created from `bucket1`. Instead I want to use the third element of `array1`, namely *bucket1*.

Something like:

```
declare -a ${array1[2]}=${array1[@]}
```

So that I end up with new `bucket1` array, containing `('10' '30' 'bucket1')`

In short:
I want to copy an array, alter the copied array, apply the changes from the copied array in the original array using one of the elements from the copied array as the name of the original array.

It this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bucket1=(10 20 bucket1)
tmp=("${bucket1[@]}")
tmp[1]=30
declare -a "${tmp[2]}"=("${tmp[@]}")
```

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Hmm that doesn't work. Try one-by-one

```
for i in ${!tmp[@]}; do declare "${tmp[2]}[$i]"="${tmp[i]}"; done
echo ${bucket1[1]}
```

```
30
```

---

This is MUCH easier in ksh93

```
$ bucket1=(10 20 bucket1)
$ nameref tmp=bucket1
$ tmp[1]=30
$ echo ${bucket1[1]}
30
```

Comment: +1 For future reference, the `ksh93` solution will work in `bash` 4.3, replacing `nameref` with `declare -n`.

Comment: I had to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04 to get Bash 4.3. Then I used the ksh93 solution, with the help from chepner. It works exactly how I want it to. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read -ra` instead of `declare` here:

```
$> bucket1=('10' '22' 'bucket1')
$> array1=("${bucket1[@]}")
$> array1[1]='30 50'
$> declare -p array1
declare -a array1='([0]="10" [1]="30 50" [2]="bucket1")'

$> IFS=$'^G' && read -ra "${array1[2]}" < <(printf "%s^G" "${array1[@]}")
$> declare -p "${array1[2]}"
declare -a bucket1='([0]="10" [1]="30 50" [2]="bucket1")'
$> declare -p bucket1
declare -a bucket1='([0]="10" [1]="30 50" [2]="bucket1")'
```

All these `declare -p` have been used to print the array contents and can be removed in real script.

`^G` is typed using <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> together.

Comment: Reading from a here string will split space-containing elements of the array into separate elements in the new array. To see, change the first element of `bucket1` to something like `'10 4'`.

Comment: I know that very well and provided this solution as proof of concept only since OP's input doesn't have spaces in array elements.

Comment: @chepner: Check updated answer now for making it safe for string with white spaces.

Comment: Well, as long as there is a character known to be absent from any element of the array, this will work, but this will not work in general.

Comment: Probability of a control character e.g. `^G` in input! How realistic do you think that can be :)

Comment: Not very, but I don't like to rely on chance :)

Answer (score 0):

With a little work, you can get the value of the array in a form suitable for use in the argument to `declare`.

```
IFS="=" read _ value <<< "$(set | grep '^array1=')"
declare -a "${array1[2]}=$value"
```

The quotes around the command substitution are necessary to work around a bug that is fixed in `bash` 4.3. However, if you have that version of `bash`, you can use named references to simplify this:

```
declare -n tmp=${array1[2]}
tmp=("${array1[@]}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
unset ${array1[2]}
declare -a ${array1[2]}="`echo ${array1[@]}`"
```

First we clear the array and then the output of echo will be stored in the new array name.

Comment: This sets the first element of the new array to the entire contents of the original array.